# Java: auto-generated test client for a WS

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic-10.x

is there a way to auto-generate in Java a test client for a web service? I have a WS with an operation `foo(String a, String b)`, I need to generate a web client (a JSP page) with a simple form and a "send" button to call the operation foo and show the response. I'd like to auto-generate this test client so that if the operation changes to `foo(String a, String b, String c)` I don't need to edit manually the client page to add the new "c" field, but this happens automatically compiling it. Is it possible to do this?
Otherwise, does Weblogic 10.3.6 provide some feature like this?

Comment: Axis-2 have this option by default, while you create a webservice axis-2 will create jsp client as well. I'm not sure about weblogic.

Comment: Thanx. What about JAX-WS?

Comment: you can use `wsimport` to generate client artifacts from the given WSDL file. Take a look at this sample/tutorial: [using-wsimport-tool-to-generate-client](http://ayazroomy-java.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-wsimport-tool-to-generate-client.html)

Comment: You can use eclipse to create webservice client, But still its not jsp. May be you can take a look at it http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html

Comment: Thanx but wsimport only generates the classes to access the WS, but not a web interface to call them. My need is to auto-generate a test client that provides a web page for a user that wants to test the service and see results.

Comment: I've tried with Eclipse but there is no JSP as well

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use glassfish webservice tester http/https url. It automatically detects the changes on deployment. Not sure about Weblogic.